What would be the legal status of Jean Valjean and Cosette in the present day?
In Victor Hugo's novel, Jean Valjean tells a dying mother that he will care for her daughter, Cosette. The mother gives him a letter authorizing him to care for Cosette. He goes to the inn where the daughter is being cared for, and pays off her expenses. They disappear into a convent for about eight years, and then begin living openly in Paris. He always treated Cosette well, and they had plenty of money.
I'm curious: if such a sequence of events were to play out in the present day (in the United States, let's say), how would the legal system react? (I'm not sure exactly how anyone would know; presumably some situation would arise when a birth certificate would be needed.) Is there some concept of “common law adoption,” or would the courts start from scratch in determining who should take care of Cosette? Would Valjean be guilty of a crime?

I don't recall. Was Cosette a legitimate child of her father? If not, at the time, Cosette's father would not legally be a parent of his child.

@ohwilleke: No, Cosette's father (Tholomyès) seduced her mother (Fantine), but did not marry her, and abandoned her before Cosette was born.

@NateEldredge So, under the French law of the time, Cosette legally doesn't have a father. Of course, in any modern jurisdiction, Tholomyès would be legally the father if his paternity was established. So, his role would depend upon how far you want to take the legal time warp to the future.

Her legal guardian
new-south-wales
Probably.
A living parent can appoint a guardian for their child by deed Guardianship of Infants Act (NSW) 1916, subject to the Family Law Act (Cth) 1975. The appointment is valid without taking the matter to court, although the court can intervene if there is a dispute, for example, if the other parent objects to the appointment.
Now, it’s unlikely that the letter the mother wrote meets all the requirements of a deed but, in modern jurisprudence, courts typically look at substance over form - if the document shows a clear intention to appoint Jean as guardian, then the court may overlook defects in the formalities, particularly if it is uncontested.
Notwithstanding, Jean is clearly a person with “sufficient interest” in the child and can therefore apply to the Federal and Family Court to be appointed guardian irrespective of the letter. Again, if no one objects and it’s in the best interest of the child, he will be named guardian.
At a more fundamental level, unless someone raises an issue over the relationship, the state is not going to get involved. Many people care for children without having a formal legal relationship. Anecdotally, as a parent, you are hardly ever required to formally prove your relationship to your child.

@NateEldredge (1) While adoption requires a termination of parental rights, guardianship generally does not. If there had been a desire to later formalize an adoption rather than a guardianship, the father's parental rights could probably be terminated for desertion/abandonment. (2) In the modern world, the letter would expire on the mother's death but would position him to be a first priority person to be appointed as a guardian. In the modern bureaucratic world, a court appointment would probably be necessary when the mother died (I don't recall when that happened in the story).

The law is generally similar in most U.S. jurisdictions, although, at present, in Colorado, e.g., a guardianship by written instrument must be renewed basically every 12 months to have continued validity. I don't know the state of the law today in France, which is where the story takes place.
